# Parts of scene are cut off in the camera's view

Tags: camera

Because the ground in my scene is very large a big portion is being cut off in the camera view.

[image]

[image]
When I adjust the scale the camera other mesh cut from the scene.

[image]

I do not want to change the angle of the view. The ground is huge yet its not visible in the camera. Any suggestions on how to resolve this would be appreciated.

Comment: you camera is set to orthographic

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the clip start/end for your camera's Object Data if you are working with a small or large scene.

[image]

In addition to this often causing problems, it looks like in your blend file your camera is sinking below the ground:

[image]

I expect this is causing the clipping you are seeing. I made a new camera that isn't clipping the ground, and it looks good.

[image]

[image]

Comment: i tried did not work